# How to dynamically get right Page Class in Before-Hook with Selenium/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, hook

i have a Selenium/Cucumber Infrastructure for testing website´s with at least 3 Pages(Edit, Overview, Send). All my Page Classes are extending from AbstractPage which only have a LinkedHashMap with all the WebElements and Driver in it. I also have a PageManager to setCurrentPage and getPage. Before every Scenario i have to launch the WebSite and set the Page to EditPage. I want to write a method to get the EditPage dynamically from my Before-Hook Step because every Site has another name and is in another package.

For example: I launch the Test for "Website1" and after the WebDriver is started and the URL is ready i now need to get my "WebSite1EditPage.java" as AbstractPage to set the current page.

**AbstractPage.java:**

```
public abstract class AbstractPage {
public Map<String, AbstractWebElement> webElementMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Map<String, AbstractWebElement> getListOfWebElementType(WebElementType type) {
    Map<String, AbstractWebElement> WebElementMapOfType = new HashMap<>();
    webElementMap.forEach((description, value) -> {
        if(value.getWebElementType() == type)
            WebElementMapOfType.put(description,value);
    });
    return WebElementMapOfType;
}

    public AbstractPage getPage(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

**PageManager.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PageManager {
   private AbstractPage currentPage;
   private String destination;

   public AbstractPage getPage()  {
       return currentPage;
   }

   public void setCurrentPage(AbstractPage page) {
       currentPage = page;
   }
}
```

**WebSite1EditPage.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
public class WebSite1EditPage extends AbstractPage {
   public WebSite1EditPage(WebDriver driver) {
      ...All WebElement Objects from webElementMap (webElementMap.put(...))
   }
```

**WebSite1EditPageSteps.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSite1EditPageSteps  {
private final PageManager pageManager;
private final WebSite1EditPage webSite1EditPage;

@Given("Launch the WebSite1")
public void launchTheWebSite1() {
    pageManager.setCurrentPage(webSite1EditPage); //This is the step i want to write in Before-Hook, because i have to do this for every another website, i allways need the EditPage to Start my tests
}
```

**Hooks.java**

```
   @Before
   public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario){
       String feature = getFeatureName(scenario.getId());
       endPointManager.setFormToken(feature);
       log.info("This Step open the Browser and launch the " + feature + " Website."); //Feature is the WebSite Name in my case
       String url = connectionProperties.getWebSite().getUrlAsString() + 
       endPointManager.getEndPoint();
       webDriver.get(url);
       assertThat(webDriver.getCurrentUrl()).isEqualTo(url);

       String pageName = getFeatureName(scenario.getId()) + "EditPage"; // getFeatureName(scenario.getId() gives me my WebSite Name in this case here "WebSite1"
       pageManager.getPage(pageName); //Something like this is my idea. But its not working because, String cannot be Converted to AbstractPage. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The method with @Before hook, would probably run before the method with @Given annotation, so I think you should call setPage method in @Before hook, then call the page in the method named launchWebSite1()

Something like this may work:

```
    @Before
   public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario){
       String feature = getFeatureName(scenario.getId());
       endPointManager.setFormToken(feature);
       log.info("This Step open the Browser and launch the " + feature + " Website."); //Feature is the WebSite Name in my case
       String url = connectionProperties.getWebSite().getUrlAsString() + 
       endPointManager.getEndPoint();
       webDriver.get(url);
       assertThat(webDriver.getCurrentUrl()).isEqualTo(url);

       String pageName = getFeatureName(scenario.getId()) + "EditPage"; //This may be unnecessary
       WebSite1EditPage webSite1EditPage = new WebSite1EditPage(webDriver);
       pageManager.setCurrentPage(webSite1EditPage);
```

And in @Given method, you can call the page like:

```
@Given("Launch the WebSite1")
public void launchTheWebSite1() {
    WebSite1EditPage webSite1EditPage = pageManager.getCurrentPage();
}
```

Not sure this will work, but I hope it helps.

Best Regards.